# Getting a 400 error whenever I try to Upload an image to an Amazon Web Services S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

Hi,

Please bear with me as I'm a newbie on this.

I'm trying to upload image files to an Amazon Web Services S3 bucket using NodeJS Knox client but I keep getting a 400 error every time I try. I think it could be an authorization issue as I can't find any errors on my code in NodeJS.  I printed the knox client object to the console after it does the upload and I get this part in it, not sure if it's telling me that AWS is not authorizing me:

agent: 
 
   Agent { 
     domain: null, 
     _events: { free: [Function] }, 
     _eventsCount: 1, 
     _maxListeners: undefined, 
     defaultPort: 443, 
     protocol: 'https:', 
     options: { path: null }, 
     requests: {}, 
     sockets: 
      { 'photogridjose.s3.amazonaws.com:443:::::::::': 
         [ TLSSocket { 
             _tlsOptions: 
              { pipe: null, 
                secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {}, 
 singleUse: true }, 
                isServer: false, 
                requestCert: true, 
          ***      rejectUnauthorized: true,**    
                session: undefined, 
                NPNProtocols: undefined, 
                ALPNProtocols: undefined, 
                requestOCSP: undefined }, 
             _secureEstablished: false, 
             _securePending: false, 
             _newSessionPending: false, 
             _controlReleased: true, 
             _SNICallback: null, 
             servername: null, 
             npnProtocol: null, 
             alpnProtocol: null, 
             **authorized: false,   *** 
             authorizationError: null, 
             encrypted: true, 
             _events: 
              { close: 
                 [ [Function], 
                   { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function] }, 
                   [Function: onClose] ], 
                end: 
                 [ { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function: onend] }, 
                   { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function: onHangUp] } ], 
                finish: [Function: onSocketFinish], 
                _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd], 
                secureConnect: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function] }, 
                connect: { [Function: bound onceWrapper] listener: [Function] }, 
                secure: [Function], 
                free: [Function: onFree], 
                agentRemove: [Function: onRemove] }, 
             _eventsCount: 9, 
             connecting: true, 
             _hadError: false, 
             _handle: 
              TLSWrap { 
                bytesRead: 0, 
                _externalStream: [External], 
                fd: -1, 
                _parent: 
                 TCP { 
                   bytesRead: 0, 
                   _externalStream: [External], 
                   fd: -1, 
                   reading: [Getter/Setter], 
                   owner: [Circular], 
                   onread: null, 
                   onconnection: null, 
                   writeQueueSize: 0 }, 
                _parentWrap: undefined, 
                _secureContext: SecureContext { context: SecureContext {}, 
 singleUse: true }, 
                reading: false, 
                owner: [Circular], 
                onread: [Function: onread],

I used the AWSAccessKeyId & AWSSecretKey that I was given by AWS and changed the S3 bucket's policy so it's set to read/write for everyone.
This is my bucket policy doc:

{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Id": "Policy150032*******",
     "Statement": [
         {
              "Sid": "Stmt1500*********", 
              "Effect": "Allow", 
              "Principal": "*", 
              "Action": [ 
                   "s3:GetObject", 
                   "s3:PutObject", 
                   "*" 
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Myphotogrid/*" 
          }
     ]
}


Here's my CORS document:
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>* </AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET </AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>POST </AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>PUT </AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedHeader>Authorization </AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Here's the S3 Bucket's log for that transaction:


<Error> 
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code> 
 <Message>Access Denied</Message> 
 <RequestId>37329C57F01BEC29</RequestId> 
 <HostId>
  zYNm+4zorTHrNnmHBAYPVpFfkJJ3VL1qtJ+PI9vJPRHhCb7vGhhav4YNRlbbakRJlpyab6Gfcn0=
 </HostId>
</Error>

Does anyone here have experience using AWS S3 buckets that could help?.

Comment: 400 is a bad request. This probably means your request data is invalid. Not an authorization issue. 403 would be the one you'd see if you were unauthorized. Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList) for a list of error responses.

Comment: I deleted my S3 bucket and made a new one and now I'm getting a 307 error which is a Temporary redirect, probably because the new bucket was just created.  If this fixes the issue I'll update.  It seems it was a permission issue with the S3 bucket itself.

Answer (score 0):

Made a new S3 bucket and deleted the old one, made sure permissions are right for the public to read/write to bucket,and selected the server closest to my location to store it which both solved the 400 & then later 307 errors I was getting.  I'm getting a 200 success response now and files are being uploaded to my S3 bucket without problems.